# Returning students who are placed and unplaced for an APEX pie chart

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to write a query for an APEX pie chart that shows how many students are placed on an internship and those who are not.

There's a `students` table with a primary key of `record_number` and an applications table with a foreign key pointing to `record_number`. The applications table has a `status_id` field which is the value `3`, `4` or `7` if the student is placed on an internship, and any other value means they are not placed on an internship.

This is my query so far which successfully shows those who are placed on an internship:

```
SELECT NULL AS link, 'Placed' AS label, COUNT(*) AS value
FROM tbl_students students
JOIN tbl_applications applications USING (record_number)
WHERE applications.status_id IN (3, 4, 7)
```

This successfully returns one row which shows how many students are placed on an internship, however I need it to return one more row which shows the amount of students who are not placed on an internship, while still only having those three fields (`link`, `label` and `value`).

To give an example, if I have 10 students in the database, 4 of which are placed on an internship, the query should return these rows:

```
link    |    label    |    value
---------------------------------
(null)  | Placed      | 4
(null)  | Unplaced    | 6
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The following assumes that there is exactly one record in tbl_applications for each tbl_students:

```
SELECT NULL AS link,
       CASE WHEN applications.status_id IN (3,4,7)
            THEN 'Placed' ELSE 'Unplaced'
       END AS label,
       COUNT(*) AS value
FROM tbl_students students
JOIN tbl_applications applications USING (record_number)
GROUP BY CASE WHEN applications.status_id IN (3,4,7)
              THEN 'Placed' ELSE 'Unplaced'
         END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sql union like this

SELECT NULL AS link, 'Placed' AS label, COUNT(*) AS value
FROM tbl_students students
JOIN tbl_applications applications USING (record_number)
WHERE applications.status_id IN (3, 4, 7)

Union

SELECT NULL AS link, 'Unplaced' AS label, COUNT(*) AS value
FROM tbl_students students
JOIN tbl_applications applications USING (record_number)
WHERE applications.status_id NOT IN (3, 4, 7)

Comment: there are alternatives using self join , but for that i need to know the structure of your tables